# parse HTML in Java to create an XML

Tags: java, html, xml, nsxmlparser

```
<TBODY>
 <TR>
 <TD colSpan=4>Detail of your Trip</TD></TR>
 <TR></TR>
  <TR>
  <TD colSpan=4>Booking Ref. : XXX</TD></TR>
   <TR></TR>
  <TR>
  <TD>Client</TD>
    <TD colSpan=2>Ticket Number</TD>
    <TD>FOID</TD></TR>
    <TR>
     <TD>Person (ADT)</TD>
   <TD colSpan=2>000000</TD>
  <TD>XXXX</TD></TR>
  <TR></TR>
  <TR>
  <TD>From: Location 1</TD>
  <TD>To : Location 2</TD>
   <TD colSpan=2>Flight : LLL</TD></TR>
     <TR>
  <TD colSpan=2></TD>
   <TD colSpan=2>Departure : 14Aug, 15:55 Latest check-in time limit : 15:25 </TD></TR>
    <TR>
    <TD colSpan=2></TD>
   <TD colSpan=2>Arrival : 17:25</TD></TR>
   <TR>
   <TD colSpan=2></TD>
   <TD colSpan=2>Class N</TD></TR>
   <TR>
  <TD>From : Location 2</TD>
  <TD>To :Location1</TD>
  <TD colSpan=2>Flight : AF2585 Resa : OK</TD></TR>
   <TR>
   <TD colSpan=2></TD>
   <TD colSpan=2>Departure : "Time" Latest check-in time limit : "Time" </TD></TR>
  <TR>
  <TD colSpan=2></TD>
  <TR>
  <TD colSpan=2></TD>
```

I would like to parse this HTML and get the details like traveler name..trip Date

and to create an XML .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some good experience with HTMLCleaner (http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/javause.php).
It is simple and creates well-formed XML.

Comment: HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
    CleanerProperties props = cleaner.getProperties();

    props.setTranslateSpecialEntities(true);  now do you think the string data contains the cleaned XML ?
    props.setTransResCharsToNCR(true);
    props.setOmitComments(true);

    // do parsing
    TagNode tagNode;

    tagNode = new HtmlCleaner(props).clean(emailContent);
    String data = tagNode.toString();

Comment: i did it like this to get it as String: final HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
String result = new SimpleXmlSerializer(cleaner.getProperties()).getXmlAsString(cleaner.clean(parseString));

Comment: A better example using XPath can be found [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/using-xpath-and-html-cleaner-to-parse-html-xml/)

Answer (score 1):

Because XSLT is some kind of holy grail which solves nearly every problem i recommend you to get your html to xhtml with "Html Tidy" or with an java library which can convert html to xhtml and then use XSLT to extract the data you'd like to use.